# Concept d'avoir du plaisir en donnant du plaisir ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Je sais qu'il existe un mot décrivant le concept de *prendre du plaisir en donnant du plaisir à quelqu'un d'autre* (il n'y a pas forcément de connotation sexuelle dans ce concept) mais j'ai oublié. C'est un mot rarement rencontré.

Ça parle à quelqu'un ?

Je ne parle pas d'altruisme", et ce n'est aucun de ces [mots-là](https://www.synonymes.com/synonyme.php?mot=altruisme) :
*bienveillance, humanité, charité, philanthropie, sympathie, abnégation, oubli de soi-même, affection, allocentrisme, bénignité, bienfait, bonté, clémence, générosité, gentillesse, longanimité, magnanimité, mansuétude, oubli.*

Comment: Jouissance, volupté, délices (des sens ou amoureuse·s) partagée·s,

Comment: Ce serait un contraire de *sadisme* ? Selon un "axe" différent de sadisme/masochisme bien sûr. Tu sais si c'était un adjectif ou un nom ?

Comment: c'est un nom @TeleportingGoat

Comment: @MickaelFM ça me rappelle le terme "people pleaser" en anglais, mais je ne connais rien de la sorte en français

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je viens de le retrouver, c'est la "[compersion](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compersion)".
Le concept Bouddhiste Mudita s'en rapproche beaucoup.

Comment: *Compersion / compersif·ve* inconnu·es du petit Robert et de l'Académie française !! Employé comme opposé à la *jalousie* (dont le contraire est *l'indifférence*), les marges d'intelligibilités sont faibles pour celles et ceux que l'illumination n'a pas encore atteints :-)